# Generate a random color on iOS in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicolor

Generate random color

```
float red   = (float)(arc4random() % 255)/255.0;  
float blue  = (float)(arc4random() % 255)/255.0;  
float green = (float)(arc4random() % 255)/255.0;  
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];
```

OR use This

change the View Background every time is unique color

```
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {  

  float red   = (float)(arc4random() % 255)/255.0;  
    float blue  = (float)(arc4random() % 255)/255.0;  
    float green = (float)(arc4random() % 255)/255.0;  
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0]; 
}
```

Comment: what the isue u faced

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: this is question or answer ... I think answer .. and may be duplicate too

Comment: if no issue, then why you asked it?

Answer (score 1):

It will generate random color for you:

```
CGFloat red   = arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0;  
CGFloat blu   = arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0;  
CGFloat green = arc4random_uniform(255)/255.0;  
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blu alpha:1.0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This for those people who are looking for a function that return a random `UIColor` object.

```
- (UIColor *)randomColor {
    CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );
    CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
    CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
    return [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
}
```